# Velocity.js - rotation around center

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I'm using Velocity.js for animation.

What's the proper way to move an SVG image, while rotating it around the center at the same time?

Comment: if you are setting value per frame, you are losing performance.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see other options to work around the bug with rotation axis.

Comment: I believe svg elements do not cause issue see [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwrJWL). For the css based elements likd divs etc, you might need to devise a way to move the x and y position of the element along with the translate.

Comment: Nope, in my case SVG animation gives the same result. I think the problem is when doing translation and rotation at the same time.

Comment: I think otherwise, I updated [the pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwrJWL) to include another rectangle which rotates around the origin where it started (the blue one) and the green one rotates around its top left corner?

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that I had to use ***x*** instead of ***translateX***. What can I do to make the SVG rotate around its center, and not around its left corner? transform-origin seems to do nothing for me.

Comment: Let me put it as a comprehensive answer as I think now fully understand your actual problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73300/discussion-between-ilya-suzdalnitski-and-arkoak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to do per frame animation if you can define the motion using combination of rotations and linear movements.

As it comes out, your issue is that you are not able to fully manage the origin of rotation.

**NOTE** : The following is applicable to not only velocity but all css transformations in general.

The **origin** of rotation is the top-left corner of the item to be rotated

Now, if you want to *move the object without moving the origin*, you can use the `translateX, translateY` properties. eg

```
.velocity({ translateX: "+=200", translateY: "25%"})
```

In order to *move the object as well as the origin*, you need to set or move its `x and y` position parameters. eg

```
.velocity({ x: "+=200", y: "25%" })
```

**Rotation around center**

As an example, if you want to rotate an object on its center,you need to

- Translate the object by -w/2 and -h/2 where the width and height is w and h.
- Rotate the object

**Rotation around an external point**

In case where you need to rotate the object around an item, simply first translate the object away from its origin by a suitable distance and then rotate it.

This [PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwrJWL) shows both examples where the green rectangle is rotated around its center and the blue one around an external point by combining translation and position correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity.js uses CSS transforms to do it's rotation. Because of this, all you actually need to do is set `transform-origin: center;` in your CSS. This changes the point around which all actions will happen.

Trying to match the rotational movement and shifting your X and Y accordingly will be a slower animation and more prone to bugs.

More information about `transform-origin` can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).